# How do I make a PDF of the JFrame (including the JScrollPane parts not shown)?

Tags: java, swing, pdf, printing, jframe

I am making a survey using Java and would like to have a printable version also. However, some of questions fall outside of the viewable area (they are in a JScrollPane). Below is the code I have for printing but it only prints the viewable part of the JFrame. Please could someone help?

```
private void printFrame(){
    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    printerJob.setPrintable(this);

    // pop up a dialog box for the end user to fine tune the options.
    if ( printerJob.printDialog() )
        {
        try
            {
            // render the component onto the printer or print queue.
            printerJob.print();
            }
        catch ( PrinterException e )
            {
            System.out.println( "Error printing: " + e );
            }
        }
    }

public int print( Graphics gr, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex ){
        if ( pageIndex > 0 )
            {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)gr;      
        g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

        double xScale = 0.33;
        double yScale = 0.33;

        g2d.scale(xScale, yScale);

        paint(g2d);

        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
```

Thanks in advance,
D

Comment: You need to reconstruct the UI in such away that it either has enough to room so that the JScrollPane's don't need to provide scrollability or create a second view without them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Arthur.
I now have it working with:

```
public void PrintFrameToPDF(File file) {
    try {
        Document d = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream(file));
        d.open();

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(PageSize.A4.getWidth(),PageSize.A4.getHeight());
        cb.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);

        Graphics2D g2d = template.createGraphics(PageSize.A4.getWidth(),PageSize.A4.getHeight());
        g2d.scale(0.4, 0.4);

        for(int i=0; i< this.getContentPane().getComponents().length; i++){
            Component c = this.getContentPane().getComponent(i);
            if(c instanceof JLabel || c instanceof JScrollPane){
                g2d.translate(c.getBounds().x,c.getBounds().y);
                if(c instanceof JScrollPane){c.setBounds(0,0,(int)PageSize.A4.getWidth()*2,(int)PageSize.A4.getHeight()*2);}
                c.paintAll(g2d);
                c.addNotify();
            }
        }


        g2d.dispose();

        d.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

If anyone has optimisations for the above, I'd love to hear from you. Thanks for the help!
D

Answer (score 0):

One PDF library can be found at http://itextpdf.com/ .